Implicit non linear formula to explicit polynomial formula.
Suppose that $\{P_n\}$ are sequential functions of polynomials of degree $n$, and $x$ is between $[-1,1]$.
Put $P_0 = 0$, and define, for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots ,$
$$P_{n+1} = P_n + \frac{ (x^2  - P_n^2) }{2}$$
My question is: What is the the explicit formula of $P_n$?
I try this:
if $n=0$ then :
$$ P_1 = a_1 * x = \frac{ (x^2) } {2} $$
But this is wrong!! Because we know that $a_i$ is a constant real number like $0.5$! not function of $x$.
((My question is about chapter 7 of rudin analysis SEQUENCES AND SERIES OF FUNCTIONS question number 23)). It says that this polynomials convergent uniformly to |x|.

What makes you think that there is an "explicit formula"?

@Somos because we have an sequential functions that uniformly convergent to |x| ; so we can talk about what is exactly P5 , what is exactly P12 and all terms .... And what makes you think that there isn't an explicit formula ? :)))

Because "explicit formula" is not a well-defined concept. Anyway, the point is to prove uniform convergence which does not require explicit formulas, but inequalities.

@Somos  Honestly, I don't know exactly, but my sixth sense tells me that the purpose of Rodin's book is that it has a explicit formula..   :)...

@Somos My purpose for knowing this explicit formula is to understanding how can i make this polynomials myself?? And the most important question, where it com from?? How should this get in mind ?

Then that should be your question instead of explicit formula.
